# How to generate .p12 Development APN certificate (with no apple developer account)

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, apn

In order to use Firebase cloud messaging, My Firebase app requires a .p12 Development APN certificate while I can not find it.

I have a free (non-developer) apple ID and used the Apple push certificate portal to create certificate , the certificate to download from portal is .pem format (not .p12)
I create the certificate using my Google App for work admin console and following the bellow link steps: 
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6080359?hl=en

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs It gives the steps for retrieving the p12 file.

Comment: This method works for Apple developer member holders who pay $99 annually. for non-member apple account holders apple push certificate portal would be the case. I am aware that apple has made it free to deploy app into the device with no membership.

Comment: It seems like without a developer Apple account we are not able to push notification for iOS

Comment: Correct, I think the push certificate you are referencing is for managing devices with an organization, Mobile Device Management (MDM) certificates. You need APNs certificates to send notifications to your iOS app.

Comment: you are right Arthur, the google procedure is for another purpose